# What does "what you would have answered were you asked the same question" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a paragraph which is about how to talk to anyone, anytime, anywhere

> To avoid stalling in a conversation, it helps to ask open-ended questions and to make open-ended statements. Ideally, you will get a great answer in return, but you cannot expect it. You have to be prepared either way, and if you get a not so great answer, such as “I don’t know,” or even a one-word reply, you can clarify the question by telling **what you would have answered were you asked the same question**

I think it may be a conditional sentence, but I don't believe in my opinion because it is different from conditional sentences I often see. Can anyone explain it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to phrase the sentence is, "Clarify the question by telling (saying) what you would have answered **if** you were asked the same question."

It is a type of conditional used for past modal verbs. Past modal verbs are could, should, would, etc. "Were" is a past tense form of the verb "to be" that applies to second-person singular (i.e. "you") and 1st and 3rd person plural ("we", "they"). In this case, "were you" is equivalent to "if you were".

> We would have gone to the party, if we were invited.

is the same as

> We would have gone to the party, were we invited.

Answer (score 1):

It's a hypothetical situation. In this case, "were you" is equivalent to "if you" and "if you were".

Imagine that you were asked the question. What would you have answered?